# Update column using another table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, multiple-columns

I have a tables that look something like this

Table1

```
Source                 OriginalCreatedDate
james@gmail.com        2022-12-24 06:01:25.000
david@gmail.com
```

Table 2

```
Source                 CreatedDate
james@gmail.com        2022-12-24 06:01:25.000
david@gmail.com        2023-08-07 02:01:25.000
```

I'm just wondering how can I update Table 1 OriginalCreatedDate column using Table2 CreatedDate column.

I believe I'll need to use the Source column to compare both tables but I'm just wondering how can I update Table1 rows that have null or '' value only. I want to ignore a row that already have OriginalCreatedDate value.

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET Original_CreatedDate = ISNULL((
        SELECT Top 1 Table2.CreatedDate
        FROM Table2
        WHERE Table2.Source = Table1.Source
    ), Table1.Original_CreatedDate)
        GO
```

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated

Comment: Use a join in your update statement. Also, you really need to get an upgrade plan sorted out. SQL Server 2012 has been fully out of support for more than a year now.

Comment: Have you have a look at the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#BasicSyntax) in the documentation? What about them didn't you understand?

Comment: @ThomA I'm not sure how to use the join like Sean mentioed.

Comment: The code that I have right now is updating everything. Pls check the code above

Comment: Such as in [this example])(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#best-practices)? Again about the xamples didn't you understand? That's not a `JOIN` is a subquery.

Comment: Is `Source` unique? Is the `Top 1` (without `ORDER BY`) supposed to signify anything meaningful, or was it just a haphazard attempt to not update all rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
SET
  OriginalCreatedDate = t2.CreatedDate
FROM
  Table1 AS t1
  JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Source = t2.Source
WHERE
  (t1.OriginalCreatedDate IS NULL) OR (t1.OriginalCreatedDate = '')
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you so much for this and look like it work but quick question. Do you know why the datetime format is changed in Table 1 OriginalCreatedDate Column?. It didn't inserted the same format as Table2 CreatedDate column.  Forexample, Table2 = 2022-12-24 06:01:25.000 but it look like this in Table 1 "Dec 24 2022  6:01AM"

Comment: because you're using varchar and not date data type

Comment: @siggemannen Oh ok, is there a way I can fix it to have the same format is Table2?

Comment: @aasenomad What data types are you using for OriginalCreatedDate and CreatedDate?

Comment: @ivanyuzafatau I'm using Varchar for both of them. CreatedDate column is using this format   CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')

Comment: @aasenomad `I'm using Varchar` WHY?

Comment: @aasenomad using varchar for dates is a terrible decision. [Why?](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @aasenomad in the question you say table1 could have null or ''. How does this update solve for ''?

Comment: @Stuckat1337 You can just add "OR (t1.OriginalCreatedDate = '')" to WHERE.

Comment: Yes, I know how to fix it, I was just asking the OP how it solved their problem without it.

Answer (score 1):

Really, you should not be using `varchar` for either of these columns. You're getting formatting differences because you're storing *strings* when you shouldn't have to worry about format *at all* because *date/time values are not strings*.

To deal with your current scenario, where the source *or* the target can be NULL, an empty string, any number of spaces, or junk, I would do it this way:

```
UPDATE t1 SET Original_CreatedDate = 
    CONVERT(char(11), TRY_CONVERT(date, t2.CreatedDate), 120)
    + ' ' +
    CONVERT(char(12), TRY_CONVERT(time, t2.CreatedDate), 121)
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS t2
ON t1.Source = t2.Source
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, 
  NULLIF(RTRIM(t1.Original_CreatedDate),'')) IS NULL;
```

> [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/VMvvOPNU?hide=4)

But really you should fix those columns so they're the right data type in the first place, or at least protect them with constraints so junk gets rejected. If both columns were `datetime`, the solution would be much simpler.

Comment: It looks like RTRIM will be superfluous here. "NULLIF('     ','')" will also return NULL.

Comment: @Ivan I'd rather be explicit anyway than save 5 characters and rely on memorization of one of the more inconsistent things in SQL Server (how it handles trailing spaces).